# Rails: two references from one table/model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord

I have generated:

```
rails g model EventTime name:string start_time:datetime post:references city_id:integer
```

and the models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :event_times

class EventTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :city, class_name: 'Post', foreign_key: "city_id"
```

In the `Post` table we have a row `city_id` with value.

but when I try to create a new `event_time` like here:

```
@post = Post.find(1)
  @event = @post.event_times.build(name: '123')
  @event.save
```

After save I get only the `post_id` saved right and the `city_id` is NULL

I can not find my mistake.

Tips to Improve the code are also welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Post` model, the `has_many` relation with event times references events with `post_id` as the foreign key. I do not know why you want to store the same `post_id` in two columns. But to do so you should edit your code as follows.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :event_times
  has_many :event_locations, foreign_key: "city_id", class_name: "EventTime"
end
```

Though if you build an instance of the `EventTime` class using `@post.event_times.build(name: '123')` it will assign the post id in `post_id` and `city_id` will be `nil` and if you build it using `@post.event_locations.build(name: '123')`, `city_id` will be assigned and `post_id` will be `nil`. So the best way is to assign one of the columns yourself like `@post.event_times.build(name: '123', city_id: @post.id)`